# What's the way to get the http request's timeline using java api

Tags: java, performance, http, web

tools like httpwatch and firebug net panel can list timeline, including dns resolve time, time to setup connection or so on;
my question is how to get such information in java if i send out an urlconnection? thx

Answer (score 0):

Tools such as httpwatch and firebug issue at http GET request, parse the [HTML] response, and then recursively for each resource (javascripts, images) found in the HTML repeat the same while timing the operations. You can do it yourself in a couple of days. There is an API that supports HRML parsing: http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

You can also look at JPCAP for low-level packet capture API: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpcap/

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Slava Imeshev

Comment: thx, this is to some extent similar; but it's not exactly match the dns resolve time, time to setup connections or so on